# Terraform provision to multiple accounts

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I use terraform to deploy lambda to one aws account and s3 trigger for lambda in other. Because of that, I created two separate folders and each of them holds state of specific account.

However, I'd like to merge everything into one template. Is it possible to do it? Example:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "${var.aws_profile}"
  region  = "eu-west-1"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias  = "bucket-trigger-account"
  region = "eu-west-1"
  profile = "${var.aws_bucket_trigger_profile}
}
```

I want thie following resource to be provisioned by aws bucket-trigger-account. How can I do it?

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket_notification" "bucket_notification" {
  bucket = "${var.notifications_bucket}"

  lambda_function {
    lambda_function_arn = "arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1-xxx"
    events              = ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"]
    filter_suffix       = ".test"
  }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you see the `alias` syntax on the provider block? Did you read the [docs on configuring multiple providers](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#multiple-provider-instances)?

Answer (score 2):

Found out that simply using provider argument on resource let's you use a different provider for that resource: `provider = "aws.bucket-trigger-account"`